# I have eaten / had eaten / ate seaweed when I was in Thailand three years ago

Tags: difference, present-perfect, past-perfect, past-simple

[quora.com](https://www.quora.com/Can-we-use-simple-past-to-follow-present-perfect-in-one-sentence/answer/Jihad-Mo-1?ch=10&oid=59422367&share=fb7fa80e&target_type=answer):

1a) I **have eaten** seaweed when I was in Thailand three years ago.

My variants:

1b) I **had eaten** seaweed when I was in Thailand three years ago.

1c) I **ate** seaweed when I was in Thailand three years ago.

What's the difference between them? Thanks!

Comment: What do you think the difference is? We expect you to put in a little effort.

Comment: Ronald Sole, I think 1a & 1b are possible if the speaker wants to emphasize the fact that he has/had eaten seaweed. Did you think he hasn't? He **has**! Did you doubt he could? He **had**! Do you agree with such an interpretation?

Comment: The answer is 1c).  The construction ** I have eaten when......** is incorrect although you will often hear it on radio/TV, as in **Two people have been killed when a bomb exploded.**  BBC news writers are particularly guilty.  **I had eaten seaweed....** would only work if it preceded some other action, as in: **I had eaten seaweed before I was taken ill and rushed to hospital when I was in Thailand three years ago.**.

Comment: Ronald Sole, maybe BBC newsreaders want to show that the news is still topical the moment they are saying it. Can "I have eaten seaweed when I was in Thailand three years ago" be viewed from the same angle? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually,

> I have eaten seaweed when I was in Thailand three years ago

is not at all idiomatic.

Your 1b

> I ate seaweed when I was in Thailand three years ago

is idiomatic and probably how a native speaker would interpret the first, unidiomatic sentence of 1a.

> I have eaten seaweed, but not before I was in Thailand three years ago.

The preceding sentence is idiomatic and shows that present perfect and simple past can coexist in the same sentence.

> I had eaten seaweed when I was in Thailand three years ago

is not idiomatic.

> I had eaten seaweed before I was in Thailand three years ago

is idiomatic and probably how a native speaker would interpret 1c.

I shall not try to define a complete set of rules for when combining different tenses in the same sentence is idiomatic. But “when” does not imply a temporal sequence whereas “before” and “after” do. I doubt that most sentences with one tense in the main clause and a different tense in a clause fronted by “when” will be completely idiomatic.

**EDIT**: See the comment by Stangdon on this answer. I agree that there are some contexts where sentence 1c would be idiomatic. Absent a context that establishes a temporal structure sufficient to clarify the meaning of “when,” I continue to find 1c unidiomatic.

Comment: As far as I understand, perfect tenses can be used to emphasize a result of an action that was finished. From this point of view, can't the sentences with "have eaten" and "had eaten" be correct? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, perfect tenses can be used for emphasis. They are also used to indicate relations in time. In sentences with time markers, the temporal aspect is what is idiomatic, not the emphatic aspect.

Comment: I have to disagree that "I had eaten (etc.)" is not idiomatic, and your suggestion of "...before I was in Thailand three years ago"  changes the meaning.  To me, the original sentence is perfectly clear in a context like "Last year, George asked me if I had ever eaten seaweed; I had eaten seaweed when I was in Thailand three years ago."

Comment: @stangdon Please see edit.